# validating a form in php without multiple insertions

Tags: php, html

This is the code. I am trying to create a form for users to fill in the products they will be advertising on the index.php form of the website. This page will be refreshed every minute from the meta tag definition (if you have a solution for a real time validation and update please
 I will very much appreciate).
 The main problem is whenever the form is posted it is continuously inserted into the MySQL database
 after every page refresh, and that is what I am trying to prevent.
 Thanks and anyother proposal will be highly welcomed

```
 <html>

 <body>

 <form action='' method='POST' name=''>

 Name: <input type='text' name='name' value='' />

 Price: <input type='text' name='price' value='' />

 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='validate' />
 </form>

 <?php

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $price=$_POST['price'];

 $sql="INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('','"$name"','"$price"')";

 // and so on
 }

 ?>


 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: use a redirect from the post landing page

Answer (score 0):

This could be done, with sessions, or by checking duplicate entries in database, but, also as stated in the comment section a re-direct solution to another page could server as a quick fix like, if the query it successful

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('','"$name"','"$price"')";

 if($sql){
     header('Location: foo.php'); 
 }
```

And, in `foo.php` you can write the following

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){
  $page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  header("Location: $page");
  exit();
}
```

Even though `$_SERVER` variables are not 100% reliable, in this approach, every time a data is submitted in your database, it will redirect to another page, so it will work as you want it.

Answer (score 0):

its occurring because once `$_POST['submit']` is submitted then after each refresh `if (isset($_POST['submit'])`  will return true and will insert the data after every one minute because you are refreshing that page from meta.

1. either dont use that refresh or,
2. add `header('Location: index.php');` just before **`?>`**